# NUnit: What is the most concise way to assert whether an IEnumerable contains an object of a certain type?

Tags: linq, unit-testing, nunit

I have a method named *RenderContent* which returns `object[]`
In my unit test, I need to assert that this array does not contain any objects of type `VerifyRequest`

At the moment, I'm using the following `Assert` statement. Is there anything more concise?

```
Assert.That(
    domain.RenderContent().OfType<VerifyRequest>().Count(),
    Is.EqualTo(0)
);
```

I prefer to use fluent syntax. Note also that *RenderContent* returns `object[]`, not `IQueryable<object>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using NUnit 2.5, you could use something like:

```
Assert.That(domain.RenderContent(), Has.None.InstanceOf<VerifyRequest>());
```

But I'm not sure  if other unit test frameworks support this assert-style.

Answer (score 12):

Although I don't know the exact NUnit syntax for IsFalse assertion, the best fit for this kind of test is the `Any` extension method:

```
Assert.IsFalse(domain.RenderContent().OfType<VerifyRequest>().Any());
```

It might be tempting to use the `Count` method, but `Any` is more efficient, as it will break on the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

The Any extension method, which can be given a lambda expression:

```
Assert.IsFalse(domain.RenderContent().Any(i => i is VerifyRequest));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten it a tad by using the Assert.AreEqual method instead:

```
Assert.AreEqual(domain.RenderContent().OfType<VerifyRequest>().Count(), 0);
```

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't NUnit have a built in syntax-helper for this?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the Assert.AreEqual approach; NUNit uses Assert.That for the internal Assert, STringAssert, etc objects.  I like just doing Assert.AreEqual(0, domain.RenderContent().OfType().Count()); to check for the counts.

This way, it checks directly that no objects of a type have any number of records, but to a point the variations you see are preference and they all are equally valid.  You have to choose what you like for your style of development.